# why is iPhone launch image not lining up with main screen background image at transistion?

Tags: iphone, ios, launch

Background:

- I have an iPhone application for which I want the launch image to be exactly the same as the background image for the main screen - so that upon loading the "launch image" is shown, then when the apps loads the main screen the background image will be the same, and perfectly line up so there is no change in background perceived
- in the main screen viewDidLoad I load the same image into a UIImageView that takes up the entire window

Issue:

- what I get is there is a vertical offset, so there is a noticeable change during the transition
- it appears the issue main be in the vertical alignment for the launch image, in that it appears the top of the launch image starts higher than the bottom of that "carrier - time - battery" bar - it seems this launch image may be positioned for it's tops to be from the top of this
- whereas the top of the background image for the main screen (once it loads) is from the bottom point of the "carrier - time - battery" bar

QUESTION:  Why is there an offset?  How best to fix this?

thanks

Comment: And, that bar is called *"Status Bar"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use two different images for your start up image & background image.

Just set your background imageView's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeBottom` will fix this problem.

for example:

`backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;`

Comment: oh - I just noticed with this approach that when I go into Landscape mode with the device, then the image no longer aspect fits across all of the screen (so there are vertical edge bars present that aren't filled with the image)...how would change the approach to also allow for this?

Comment: Because there are different size between Portrait Mode (320*460) and Landscape Mode (480*300), you have to make two background image for the two size. Let the UIImageView automatically stretch the image will cause the problem you were trying to solve at the first time, and will also make your image looks fuzzy.

Comment: somehow this solution doesnt work for iphone5. iphone4 works fine. it get stretch badly. any idea?

Comment: @MickeyCheong What is the size of your image? Have you tried using a bigger image like 1136 x 640?

Answer (score 1):

The Default.png has to be 320x480(640x960@2x) your view after the startup is only 320x460(640x920@2x) because of the Statusbar.

Try to use 2 different Backgroundimages 320x480 for the startup(top 20px can be blank) and 320x460(640x920@2x) for your app.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for standard and retina on iPhone and iPad in Portrait or Landscape with or without the Tab Bar. This is necessary because the iPhone Launch Image overlaps the status bar, but the iPad one does not. Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            [self.backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]]];
        else
            [self.backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default-Portrait" ofType:@"png"]]];
    } else {
        [self.backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default-Landscape" ofType:@"png"]]];
    }
 
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        self.backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -20);
    else 
        self.backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Images used are:

- Default~iphone.png
- Default@2x~iphone.png
- Default-Portrait~ipad.png
- Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape~iphone.png
- Default-Landscape~ipad.png
- Default-Landscape@2x~iphone.png
- Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png

In Interface Builder put your background image in like this:

[image]